# Data Analysis and Dummy Variables

Tags: categorical-data

Do I create a dummy variable for each of the categories (4) in Ethnicity for example?  Someone informed me to only create 3 and not 4.
Categories: Caucasian/White; Hispanic American; African American; Asian American.

Please explain... :)

Comment: When fitting linear models in R with lm() or glm(), variables encoded as factors will automatically be coded as k-1 dummy variables, where k is the number of levels in the factor.

Comment: Adding as many dummy variables as categories is called the dummy variable trap. I think you will be able to find information about it here or in the www. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49210548/dummy-variable-trap-in-linear-regression

Answer (score 0):

General practice is that for linear regression, when you have a set of n mutually exclusive exhaustive categories (that is, everyone is in exactly one category), that n-1 dummy variables be used. This is because knowing the values of the first n-1 dummy variables completely determines the nth value. For a simple example, if you have everyone categorized as male or female, you don't need to have a dummy variable for both; the dummy variable for one will simply be the reverse of the other. In your example, if everyone is categorized in exactly one of your ethnicity categories, then once you know whether they are Caucasian/White, and you know whether they are Hispanic American, and you know whether they are African American, then you know whether they are Asian American, so you don't need all four columns. For a linear regression, not only is including all n dummy variables more work than needed, it makes the columns linearly dependent, which can cause problems.

If the categories aren't mutually exclusive (that is, some people are in more than one category), or aren't exhaustive (some people aren't in any), then you should include dummy variables for all the categories. Also, there are types of analyses other than regression for which including all columns can be useful.